# "Directory cache", "directory mirror" and "directory server". Are they synonymous terms in the context of the Tor network?

Tags: directory

As I understand it, Tor clients can download "descriptors" from "directory caches" instead of download them directly from the directory authorities. This is to avoid overloading the network.

But I have seen that these three terms are sometimes used identically. In the context of the Tor network, are these three terms synonymous? Are there differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

In version the [directory spec v2](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/attic/dir-spec-v2.txt) directory cache appear to be synonymous:

> > > … Routers may act as directory mirrors (also called "caches"), …

I also took a look at the [current spec (v3)](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt) which isn't as clear about it but I got the impression that it is used interchangeably.

---

When it comes to directory servers I found this:

> > > Every Tor that is not a directory server (that is, those that do not have a DirPort set) …

I believe that includes directory caches/mirrors and authorities which would mean the meaning of directory server slightly differs.

---

Keep in mind that just because there is a formal definition for the terms, it doesn't mean it is used that way in the wild. I'd not be surprised to see all three word used synonymously.